# I am not able to install live server extension from VSIX

Tags: html, version-control, compatibility, vsix, liveserver

When I try to install any extension from vs code, It says we cannot connect to extensions marketplace.

So I tried installing it from VSIX. After downloading it, when I try to install it in VS code, it says:

Unable to install extension 'ritwickdey.liveserver' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.50.1'.